# Store weight updates for momemntum

Tags: parameters, pytorch

I am trying to implement momentum in my implementation of SGD with momentum.
From my understanding this update look like this:

```
parameters -= (lr * (p.grad*0.1 + p_delta_prev*0.9))
```

My question is how I should store my previous deltas from every update

Here is what I have in my update function:

```
#we now want to do the update with momentum
#momentum takes derivative, multiplies it by 0.1, then takes the previous update,
#multiplies it by 0.9 and we add the two together
#alpha = 0.1, beta = 0.9;  p-=grad*0.1 + p*0.9
def update(x,y,lr):
    wd = 1e-5
    y_hat = model(x)
    # weight decay
    w2 = 0.
    for p in model.parameters(): w2 += (p**2).sum()
    # add to regular loss
    loss = loss_func(y_hat, y) + w2*wd
    loss.backward()
    with torch.no_grad():
        for p in model.parameters():
            #p.grad is the slope of the line of that parameter
            #current_p-previous_p to get difference
            p_update = (lr * (p.grad*0.1 + p*0.9))
            p.sub_(p_update)
            p.grad.zero_()
    return loss.item()
```

Here the `p*0.9` should be replace by the p_delta_prev. But how should I store these deltas for every parameter? If I save them to a tensor wouldn't I would be effectively copying the weight deltas to memory making my model two times the size. What would be a good way to accomplish this? I do not want to use an inbuilt function that does that activation for me. I did look into the pytorch sgd.py and it looks like the store the states.

I have updated the code:

```
#we now want to do the update with momentum
#momentum takes derivative, multiplys it by 0.1, then takes the previous update,
#multiplies it by 0.9 and we add the two together
#alpha = 0.1, beta = 0.9;  p-=grad*0.1 + p*0.9
p_delta = {}
def update(x,y,lr):
    wd = 1e-5
    y_hat = model(x)
    # weight decay
    w2 = 0.
    for p in model.parameters(): w2 += (p**2).sum()
    # add to regular loss
    loss = loss_func(y_hat, y) + w2*wd
    loss.backward()
    with torch.no_grad():
        i = 0
        for p in model.parameters():
            #p.grad is the slope of the line of that parameter
            if i not in p_delta:#check if key exists
                p_delta[i] = torch.zeros_like(p)
            p_update = (lr *p.grad) + (p_delta[i]*0.9)
            p_delta[i] = p_update.clone()
            p.sub_(p_update)
            p.grad.zero_()
            print((p_delta[i]))
            i+=1
    return loss.item()
```

I think the code in the Excel spreadsheet is incorrect. Jeremy seems to show: `lr* ((p.grad*0.1) + (p_delta[i]*0.9))` but many tutorials seem to show: `(lr *p.grad) + (p_delta[i]*0.9)` If we implement Jeremy’s code the loss actually is slower than vanilla GD. The part of the video is here: https://youtu.be/CJKnDu2dxOE?t=6581

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does store the parameter momenta in a dictionary, indexed by their names, as returned by [`model.named_parameters()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.named_parameters). I don't know how to rigorously prove this, but I strongly believe it's impossible to apply momentum without using additional memory twice the size of your model.

That being said, I wouldn't worry, because model size is rarely a big factor in memory consumption of the whole algorithm - keeping the intermediate network activations for backpropagation algorithm is far more expensive. Taking the VGG-16 network as an example, it has 138 million parameters (figure taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28242883/4280242)), which amounts to slightly more than 0.5gb if stored in single precision. Compare this with 6gb+ found on reasonable modern GPUs.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what makes the intermediate network activations for back prop more expensive? Aren't the activations just a vector (one for each node)?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by node. Most operations in PyTorch create new tensors but also keep their inputs for the backward pass. You can assume that as the forward pass progresses, almost all intermediate values are saved (unlike NumPy, which is free to garbage collect variables which will see no further use). It's difficult to give these numbers analytically, but I suggest you take an example usecase (say training VGG on ImageNet) and try the maximum batch size your GPU can handle. Then calculate `(gpu_memory - network_weights) / batch_size` and compare to the 0.5gb used for the weights.

Comment: Ah okay, Thanks!